# How to match a html tag with perl regex?

Tags: regex, perl, match, regex-lookarounds

Given the code below, I want to match the first `form` occurrence. I found out that negative lookahead `?!` may be used to achieve that but it doesn't work. What's wrong with my regex?

```
#test
$test = "<form abc> foo </form> <form gg> bar </form>";
$test =~ m/<form[^>]*abc[^>]*>(?!.*form>.*)form>/s;
print $&;
```

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML!

Comment: Please answer how to do that, not not to do that. I just wanna learn regex.

Comment: The first step of learning regexps is accepting that there are things they are _not_ good for on their own. Parsing complex languages with nesting structures such as HTML is one of those things.

Comment: just tell me how to make this example work....
i know there must obviously be some librares to do this work but i wanna do this with regex

Comment: is it even possible with regex? its not about html but other similar cases it could be useful.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Not true. *Regular Expressions* in the CS meaning are near useless, of course, but *Perl Regexes* are a different story … they are fully fledged top-down recursive parsers, and can include arbitrary code inside the regex itself (with modern perls). I can produce patterns from inside the pattern. I can parse HTML. QED. (Not that I should or would)

Comment: @amon:  But just because you can doesn't mean it's a good way to do it.

Comment: The OP needs to find a substring matching certain pattern from a larger string. How is regular expression not the right tool?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, before explaining the regex: Use a module like `HTML::TreeBuilder` to create a document tree, then fetch your information from there. Parsing HTML with regexes is too error prone to use in the real world.

#### The Problem with your regex

Here is your string:

```
"<form abc> foo </form> <form gg> bar </form>"
```

And your regex (written expanded for readability, as with the `/x` flag):

```
<form [^>]* abc [^>]* > (?! .* form> .* ) form>
```

- `<form` anchores when the literal character sequence is found
- `[^>]*` searches for a number of non-`>` characters. Initially it matches  `abc`
- `abc` matches the literal character sequence `abc`. But because the regexp engine currently sees a  `>` it has to backtrack, until `[^>]*` matches  .
- `[^>]*` will match nothing, as the engine sees a `>`
- `>` matches the `>`
- The negative lookahead matches, when the expression `.* form .*` would not match.

  - The `.*` would consume all characters until end of string.
  - `form>` causes the engine to backtrack until the `.*` matches `foo </form> <form gg> bar </`.
  - The `.*` matches nothing, but that is okay.

So the lookahead succeeds, but it is a negative lookahead, so the assertion failes. The last part of the Regex will not even be executed.

#### Strategies

The `.*` consumes too many chararacters in our case. This is called *greedy* matching.

Non-greedy matching is written with a trailing `?` like `.*?`. This version consumes zero characters initially and first checks the next part of the pattern. If that doesn't work, it consumes another character iteratively until there is a match.

#### A better Regex

```
<form [^>]* > .*? </form>
```

Inside the opening tag, only non-`>` characters are allowed. Between the tags, any character is allowed. We do non-greedy matching, so the first end tag matches and ends the regex.

However, this solution is a bit problematic. A tolerant HTML parser would not choke on a `attr="val<u>e"`. We will. Also, the first `</form>` is matched, which is undesirable in the event that we have *nested* forms. While unproblematic in this use case, this regex is totally useless when matching `<div>`s or the like.

#### Regexp Grammars

Perl regexes are incredibly powerful and allow you to declare recursive grammars. The built-in syntax is a bit akward, but I recommend the `Regexp::Grammars` module to do that easily. Better yet, simply use a fully-fledged HTML Parser already lying around.

#### Fetching the match

The use of `$&` (and `` $` `` and `$'`) is discouraged, as it makes perl incredibly inefficient. This won't manifest itself in a small script, but its *bad style* anyway. Rather enclose your whole Regexp with parens to *capture* the match

```
m{ ( <form [^>]* > .*? </form> ) }
```

and then use `$1`.

The [`perlretut` Tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) may be a good introduction to understand Perl regexes.